# Getting a list of processes exits my for each after the first process found

Tags: vb.net, foreach, process

For my application I want to close a specific process (the on-screen keyboard / osk.exe) when a textbox loses focus. I thought I could iterate through all the processes and look for the osk.exe and to ikll it when it's found.

I made it as follow:

```
Dim psList() As Process

        psList = Process.GetProcesses()

        For Each p As Process In psList
            If p.ProcessName = "osk.exe" Then
                p.Kill()
            End If
        Next p
```

Though on the first found process it will exit the for each for some reason. In my case that was on the outlook process, just for testing I try'd to close outlook but then it exits the for each on the following process.

Looked around to find an explanation for it but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than one problem.  Remove the Try/Catch that swallows the exception first.  The process name is "osk", not "osk.exe".  And this code is likely to die with an exception since it uses a property that is not accessible for *every* process.

Be selective to avoid this problem:

```
    Dim psList = Process.GetProcessesByName("osk")
    For Each p As Process In psList
        p.Kill()
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out after my post as well, but thanks anyway!